# Rename entity in RavenDB

Tags: types, ravendb, rename

I would like to rename a class used to persist in RavenDB. I'm afraid that RavenDB wont be able to fetch documents from the DB after renaming the type. Also the entity name is used as part of the Id, so I probably need to rename those as well.

Any good pointers on how to achieve a successful rename?

Answer (score -2):

You will be able to load the old docs.
You need to watch for indexes that use the entity name, though.
You can use UpdateByIndex to make a mass update to all the old documents.

Comment: My old docs have indexes looking like this: TestDTOs/42. I would like to rename the entity from TestDTO to Test. When I query for Test entities, will Raven be able to load documents with the TestDTO-prefix as well?

Comment: I can't find any good documentation on how to patch old data when renaming entity/DTO classes, please could someone point me in the right direction...